# Find topologies that characterise smoothness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, smooth-functions

Is there a family of topologies $\tau_i$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for every map $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ we have
$$
f \text{ is continuous w.r.t. }\tau_i \forall i \iff f \text{ is smooth?}
$$

By smooth we mean infinitely often differentiable here.

Related is [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-01/S0002-9939-1971-0271969-5/home.html), proving that no topologies on $\mathbb R$ can characterize differentiability as continuity. However maybe if we consider a whole family of topologies?

Comment: Since the meaning of "smooth" varies in the literature (continuous derivative? infinitely many derivatives? [this notion?](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-12/issue-1/Smooth-functions/10.1215/S0012-7094-45-01206-3.short) etc.), you should include a definition of what you mean by "smooth". That said, somewhat related are: [Topologically, is there a definition of differentiability that is dependent on the underlying topology, similar to continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881097/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: **AND** [Which functions of one variable are derivatives ?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66462/15780) **AND** the 1976 paper [*Derivatives: why they elude classification*](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/andrew-m-bruckner-derivatives-why-they-elude-classification.pdf) by Andrew M. Bruckner **AND** the 1995-1996 survey paper [*The problem of characterizing derivatives revisited*](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/Bruckner1995.rae.1341343228.pdf) by Andrew M. Bruckner **(continued)**

Comment: **AND** the 1997-1998 paper [*Characterizing derivatives by preimages of sets*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-23/issue-2) by Krzysztof Ciesielski.